# Read different lines in one pandas dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with a cell df[0] which is like this, it has been directly imported from an .xlsx file in the very same format is shown:

List of Items:
Banana
Apple
Orange

I would like to access the second item of the list and add some strings, I am trying the following:

```
for xlsx_files in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    print "Attempting to convert file " + xlsx_files+" \n\n"
    ExceltoTxt(xlsx_files)
```

Then the function:

```
def ExceltoTxt(file):
    df=pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
             for items in df[0]:
                  print "-"+items
```

But this prints letter by letter, instead of line by line, something like:

```
-L
-i
-s
-t
-o
-f
```

When I'd ideally want

```
-List of items
-Banana
-Apple
-Orange
```

Comment: try this `for items in df:
                  print "-"+items`

Comment: Did you print out `df[0]`? Is it one string like shown in your example? Then you should first separate the header with `split(':')` and then the list elements with `.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

So, 
use apply function for changing values:

```
df[0] = df.apply(lambda row: '-{}'.format(row[0]), axis=1)
```

Then remove all column except of needed.

```
  df = df[0]
```

And save the column using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('example.txt', df.values, delimiter='\n', fmt='%s')
```

Comment: Intersting, but I made a mistake on the original post, the first line shall not have a '-', how can I do that?

Comment: Just use strip() method: df[0] = df.apply(lambda row: row[0].lstrip('-'), axis=1)